# Will my video contain errors if connection is lost while uploading to YouTube

Tags: youtube, video, upload

Right now I'm uploading a somewhat large MP4 video to YouTube (3GB). It's been over an hour and it's nearly halfway there.

In any case, I got disconnected (aprox. 5 - 10 times) while doing so, due to a faulty network adapter driver. It's now been fixed.

While the upload process seems to resume from the previous point, I'm a bit distrustful about whether the transferred file will contain any errors, because I'm yet to see a web upload form which gets it right with the resume functionality.

**Question:** Is the uploaded video going to be a perfect, bit-by-bit copy of the file I have on disk, even if internet went off several times during the transfer? If some sort of corruption is likely to happen, I'd rather manually restart it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Youtube upload engine is very powerful. Since I asked this question, I have witnessed a number of occasions in which the upload process was interrupted and then resumed without any sort of error.

I cannot testify beyong doubt whether the uploaded file is bit-identical, but it most likely is.

Comment: And the same cannot be said about Vimeo.  `:/`

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I have lost connection in mid-upload to youtube it has always picked where it left off when I re-connected. HOWEVER, this morning google chrome crashed and effectively turned my computer off...when I reconnected to the browser I had lost everything. I was using the internet in Italy (veeeeeeryy slow), 20% uploaded a 1.3GB file after 2 hours!